# How to change sign of z value in a large dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, bathymetry, xyz

I have data in an XYZ format (saved as a .txt file) that I am importing into ArcGIS and then converting to a raster using the point to raster conversion. However the Z field in the data represents a depth below the sea surface, but has been output as a positive value by the source software. In order to plot this correctly in ArcGIS is there a simple way to convert these values to negative values or to plot them as subsea? The table contains almost 40,000,000 rows so I cannot do the conversion in a text editor. I have tried using the Field Calculator function in the table, however this option is grayed out?

Comment: Field Calculator is for attribute fields, which a normal raster doesn't have (it is possible to have a raster attribute table, but only if the values are integers). As you've discovered, for performing similar calculations with rasters you need the raster calculator or one of the raster math tools. If your data was vector, there's actually a specific tool in ArcGIS just for such adjustments called [Adjust 3D Z](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000033000000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take the resulting raster from your initial conversion and use Spatial Analyst --> Math --> Times to multiply the raster by -1.